# What's the difference between a Debian suite and a Debian distribution?

Tags: debian, distributions

I know that, in Debian parlance, a "suite" is something that contains and/or is associated with several "distributions". Does this relationship have a formal definition? If so, where can I find it documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the glossary](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary) entries for [distribution](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary#dist) and [suite](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary#suite) (the wiki license [is unclear](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianWiki/LicencingTerms), so I’ll avoid copying them here).

“Suite” has a formal definition in the context of [`Release` files](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Release.22_files): it’s a section of a repository. Less formally, it corresponds to one of the release “trains”: `oldoldstable` (currently Debian 9), `oldstable` (currently Debian 10), `stable` (currently Debian 11), `testing` (the forthcoming Debian 12), `unstable`, `experimental`, and the `-security` and `-updates` variants. A distribution is typically a suite which can stand alone, *i.e.* not `experimental`, and not the security and update suites.